# How to convert a teradata table to utf8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, teradata

I am trying to upload a csv file into my teradata table `tbl` which contains Chinese and Japanese characters and teradata is not able to read those characters.

I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

But i get this error:

```
[SQLState 42000] Syntax error: Expecting the word SET or RESET. 
Error Code: 3706 
Query = ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET 
utf8;
```

Comment: Probably there was a typo in the original command or your version of mysql is too old

Answer (score 0):

Recommend utf8mb4 instead of utf8 -- some Chinese characters only work in the former.

Why are you doing the `ALTER`?  Do you already have a table with the wrong `CHARACTER SET`?

Be sure your connection is set to utf8mb4 also.